# Who has asked the most questions?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Just curious as to who has asked the most questions. Lots of people answer questions, but who has asked the most? How do you find out who has asked the most questions?

Comment: I wonder who's *answered* the most.

Comment: @Valorum good question.

Comment: @Valorum - if it's not you, i'll eat my mouse.

Comment: I was like, "Aww DVK has a pet mouse!" Then I was like "Oh."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>Taken from the [main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284601/who-asked-the-most-number-of-questions-on-stack-exchange/284604#284604)</sub>

> You can use the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE) to query sites for information like this. It does require knowledge of SQL to write queries (there is a tutorial under the SEDE help pages if you're interested), but there are a lot of existing queries you can use and you can search SEDE as you can any other Stack Exchange site.
>
> An existing query that should give you what you're looking for:
>
> - [**Who Asked the Most questions**](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/532226/who-asked-the-most-questions)

Here it appears to be @DVK-in-exile, with 664 questions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that/

Comment: Isn't it technically Satellite of Sin [now]?