# Who has answered the most questions?

Tags: support, answers

I [asked](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10164/who-has-asked-the-most-questions) who has asked the most questions, but **who has answered the most questions?**

Comment: ***[Me!](https://vinnieh.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/buffy-laughing.gif)***

Answer (score 9):

A (very) slight improvement over KutuluMike's answer:

### [Users who have answered the most distinct questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/540315/users-who-have-answered-the-most-distinct-questions)

To nobody's great surprise, it's still Valorum, with DVK trailing by a wide margin

[image]

Usual SEDE disclaimers apply:

- Deleted questions/answers are not accounted for
- SEDE updates weekly, so this result is a few days out-of-date. Seems unlikely that the top spots have changed dramatically, though

Comment: @DVK-in-exile You were right the first time, it's the visited colour for SEDE; I wanted to check that the number was correct, and I chose you as my test user. You're not the only profile I've visited, but you're the only link on that page that I clicked

Comment: thanks :) _____________

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised to be so far up that list.

Comment: Wow. I'm in the top 11?

Answer (score 8):

As usual you can use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer for this.

Taking the query Mithrandir used in your first question, we can just change "questions" for "answers" and get:

[**Who Posted The Most Answers**](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/540314/who-answered-the-most-questions)

Not surprisingly, at this point, it's Valorum and DVK.

NOTE: It's possible to post multiple answers to one question, so a better query would account for that, but that's very rare so this is a pretty good representation.

Comment: sorry, i had just run the query and his username was in my brain

Comment: Challenge accepted